# How to give classname to post if post has no content?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, query-posts, get-posts

I want to give a post a classname on the homepage (index) if the post on the single page has no content. So when the post itself exists but there is no content, I want to give a classname to that specific post/article which will be shown on the homepage.

My question: can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Are you using the `post_class` function in your template? How are you showing posts on the homepage? There's no code in your question :/ Also what are you trying to do that requires this? If the goal is to apply CSS rules, you can already style empty containers with the `::empty` pseudo selector

Answer (score 1):

As Tom J Nowell mentioned in his comment, it is not clear what do you want to accomplish. If you want to just show your empty content `div`, you can use CSS as follows:

```
div:empty {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

It will show your empty content `div` as a nice, red band.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a post class programatically to the posts that have no content you should use the following snippet inside the loop:

```
if ( empty( get_the_content() ) ) {}
```

If you're using it outside the loop to call other posts you can use:

```
<?php if (empty(get_post_field('post_content', $MY_POST_ID))): ?>

<?php endif ?>
```